# IE error when trying for( var i in window.external )

Tags: javascript

I am building an object/property dump using JavaScript. This code breaks under Internet Explorer 8 (assuming subject = window.external)

```
// Gather the property names into the keys array.
var keys = Array(); for( var i in subject ){ keys.push(i); }

/* After this I sort the keys, then loop through to get the 
   property values in subject
*/
```

If you try printing subject to the console (or alert) it comes up blank. However, other objects will print [object SomethingMeaningful].

Microsoft's documentation suggests that the object definitely has properties. It would be nice to be able to show them instead of just skipping over them. Any Ideas?

Comment: The point is, this code works fine for every object except the 'window.external' object in IE.

Comment: Link to Microsoft documentation on window.external: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535246(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I built a similar tool once... I wrapped each extraction in a try/catch block... and therefore skip window.external.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
var keys = Array(); for( var i in subject ){ keys.push(subject[i]); }
```

You can access object properties with array like syntax in JavaScript

**EDIT**

Thanks for the edit. I am not sure why that would not work for the `window.external` object. It may be that it has methods only, and no properties. Does it work under other browsers, for example, Firefox?

Comment: No - I am storing the property name in the keys array, not the property itself. The reason for this is that I am sorting the keys (using keys.sort()) before running through the properties.

Comment: Works fine for every other object (including objects which only have methods - it dumps the method name, and the first line of the code). IE is the only browser I am aware of that has the window.external object.

Comment: I thought firefox had the external object too.. for adding bookmarks?